# Can a valid certificate chain length be 1?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying a simple Java code to retrieve certificate chain for remote servers. Some websites return a chain of certificates (2,3,4..) and some just 1. My question is: Is there something wrong when I get certificate chain with length 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three cases possible:

1. They deliver a self-signed certificate
2. They deliver a certificate signed by the root certificate (rare case) which you are assumed to have as trusted
3. They deliver a certificate signed by CA certificate which they expect you to have (quite common case, as in Windows intermediate CA certificates are stored as well, so you can build a complete chain)

Case 1 can be easily checked by you but such certificates are not trusted by default (unless the user has trusted them). 
In cases 2 and 3 you need to rebuild a chain using local certificate storage as a helper.

Comment: If there is a reference, that would help.

Comment: @user1810868 RFC 5280. Certificate chain building and validation is a complicated multistage procedure. It's mainly described in this RFC (OCSP checking is defined in a different RFC, 2560). As for "popular reading" , I recommend "RSA Official Guide to Security" book - it is written in easy to understand language and covers quite a lot of crypto-related topics including certificates.